# Array Univ var ([x,y]=..T) - prolog

Tags: prolog

I saw a question asking what does `[a,b,c]=..L.` return.
When testing this I saw that it returns: `L = ['.', a, [b, c]]`.

I can't understand why this happens, I was unable to understand the nature of Univ from the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2). Understanding this will help me understand Univ.

Comment: Note that `[a,b,c] == '.'(a,[b,c]).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happends because representation of the list in prolog is a tree datastructure,like this.[image]It's top node is a "dot" left side is Head then again a dot on right if tail is not empty and head on left hand side and "dot" on right handside. When you do this you are simply creating a predicate(well , not exact a predicate but it is sometimes needed as i show an example): suppose i write:

```
V=..[somefunctor,X,Y,Z]
```

Then it will automatically construct a predicate like this:

```
   somefunctor(X,Y,Z).
```

Now Why do we need this?  Supppose i call a predicate with these terms: `predicate(somefunctor,term,term2,term3)` and predicate or rule looks something like this: `predicate(X,Y,Z,T)` and i ask you that no matter what predicate is in X, you have to call this predicate with parameters `Y,Z,T`. May be you think you call that predicate by writing like this: `X(Y,Z,T)` but unfortunately it is not allowed in prolog, so here you can use V=..[X,Y,Z,T] where X should be placed as first argument because it's predicate name and as a result you get something like this: `V = somefunctor(term,term2,term3)` and this happends internally. In order to invoke this predicate you make use of call predicate:

```
call(V) where `call/1` is a metapredicate and `V=..`  is a not logical predicate.
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to learn more about terms is to use `write_canonical/1` in a conforming Prolog system.

For example, with GNU Prolog, we obtain:

```
| ?- write_canonical([x,y]).
'.'(x,'.'(y,[]))
```

This shows:

1. the primary functor in this term is `'.'`, with *arity* 2
2. the *first* argument is `x`
3. the *second* argument is `'.'(y, [])`, which is the *list* `[y]`

This explains why `(=..)/2` yields:

```
| ?- [x,y] =.. Ls.

Ls = ['.',x,[y]]
```

and also your other example.